# ReactJS build and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, build

I'm using Google Analytics and other tools I have a problem regarding the build of ReactJS.
I was trying to get analytics from my site using react-helmet to change the title and the HTML lang parameter depending on the route the user was in.

After the build in production, Google crawl seems to kick in before the JavaScript execute so my analytics are just working for the first language and title that was set so (`<html lang="en">`) in my case.

Is there any way to get these analytics without having to generate two builds with two languages and title. Or ReactJS is just not a good solution.

Comment: Have you tried adding the google analytics tag at the bottom of your app level component?

Comment: the tag is actually in the index.html in the public folder I don't think I can put it in a component. Or maybe you mean to put it at the bottom of the index.html

Comment: Bottom of the index should work too.

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/okei4

Check out how react-ga could be used in a ReactJS project. This code is fully working so in Google Analytics I can see every page was visited.